# How to access kubernetes keys in etcd

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

## Question

How to get the Kubernetes related keys from etcd? Tried to list keys in etcd but could not see related keys. Also where is etcdctl installed?

```
$ etcdctl
bash: etcdctl: command not found..

$ sudo netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      386/etcd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      386/etcd            

$ curl -s http://localhost:2379/v2/keys | python -m json.tool
{
    "action": "get",
    "node": {
        "dir": true
    }
}
```

## Background

Installed Kubernetes 1.8.5 by following [Using kubeadm to Create a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) on CentOS 7. When I looked at [Getting started with etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/getting-started-with-etcd.html), v2/keys looks to be the end point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Usually you need to get `etcdctl` by yourself. Just download the latest `etcdctl` archive from [etcd releases page](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases).

Also, starting from Kubernetes version 1.6 it uses etcd version 3, so to get a list of all keys is:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=<etcd_ip>:2379 get / --prefix --keys-only
```

You can find all `etcdctl v3` actions using:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=<etcd_ip>:2379 --help
```

**EDIT** (thanks to @leodotcloud):

In case ETCD is configured with TLS certificates support:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints <etcd_ip>:2379 --cacert <ca_cert_path> --cert <cert_path> --key <cert_key_path> get / --prefix --keys-only
```

Comment: In case, certs are involved, here is an example command: `ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints <etd_ip>:2379 --cacert /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --cert /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node.pem --key /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node-key.pem get / --prefix --keys-only`. This command can be run from inside the etcd container if that's how it's deployed.

Comment: Instead for Minikube look below.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65958307/3673430

Answer (score 22):

Access the docker container, and run the following commmand:

`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints 127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key get / --prefix --keys-only`

Answer (score 3):

## For Minikube

(v1.17.0)
You can see the arguments exploring the pod: `kubectl describe pod -n kube-system etcd-PODNAME |less`
Here you can see the certificates path and much more.

To fastly query your etcd dictionary you can use this alias:

```sh
alias etcdctl_mini="MY_IP=$(hostname -I |awk '{print $1}'|tr -d ' '); \
    ETCDCTL_API=3; \
    sudo -E etcdctl --endpoints ${MY_IP}:2379 \
    --cacert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt' \
    --cert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.crt' \
    --key='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.key'"
```

`$ etcdctl_mini put foo bar`

Comment: [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64470257/1059372)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use etcdctl with etcd installed on CoreOS (Container Linux).
In my case the following worked (executed from CoreOS shell prompt):

```
$ sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd/peer-ca.crt --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd/peer.crt --key /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd/peer.key get --prefix / --keys-only
```

I used `sudo` as a quick solution to the permission problem "Error: open /etc/ssl/etcd/etcd/peer.crt: permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following (assuming etcd pod name is etcd-minikube).
Minikube access using etcdctl was already explained above.

```
$kubectl -it exec etcd-minikube -n kube-system -- etcdctl --cacert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt' --cert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.crt' --key='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.key' put foo bar
```

OK

```
$kubectl -it exec etcd-minikube -n kube-system -- etcdctl --cacert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt' --cert='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.crt' --key='/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/peer.key' get foo

foo
bar
```