# how to show etcd keys and values from etcdctl?

Tags: go, etcd

I know use `etcdctl get /key` to get the `/key`

I make the key from golang below .

```
cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
    Endpoints:   []string{"localhost:2379"},
    DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer cli.Close()

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*5)
resp, err := cli.Put(ctx, "sample_key", "sample_value")
defer cancel()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(ctx)
}
fmt.Println(resp.Header)
```

// cluster_id:14841639068965178418 member_id:10276657743932975437 revision:29 raft_term:2

```
time.Sleep(10 * time.Minute)
```

It`s success to make the key from clientv3. 
But I try to get it from`etcdctl` there is nothing .

```
➜  etcd-v3.3.9-darwin-amd64 git:(master) ✗ ./etcdctl ls /
➜  etcd-v3.3.9-darwin-amd64 git:(master) ✗ ./etcdctl ls /
➜  etcd-v3.3.9-darwin-amd64 git:(master) ✗ ./etcdctl get /sample_key
Error:  100: Key not found (/sample_key) [5]
➜  etcd-v3.3.9-darwin-amd64 git:(master) ✗ ./etcdctl get sample_key
Error:  100: Key not found (/sample_key) [5]
➜  etcd-v3.3.9-darwin-amd64 git:(master) ✗
```

Where did I wrong ?

Hot to fix it .

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807892/how-to-access-kubernetes-keys-in-etcd/47808794#47808794

Comment: resolve my problem !