# How to check reason for Helm install failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wanted to bring up zookeeper using `helm install .`, but it says `Error: release <servicename> failed: services "zookeeper" already exists`. I don't see anything if I execute `helm list`too. Before installing the service, I checked using `helm list` if it already exists, and it doesn't.

How to check the reason for failure?

Comment: In which namespace is it going to create resources? Check the namespace and delete the resource/clean up manually may help

Comment: I'm using the default namespace. I executed `kubectl delete services/zookeeper` and then tried doing helm install. But still no luck. Funny thing is, the same yaml file was working perfectly fine just yesterday.

Comment: Do then you need to dig into cleaning things from etcd

Comment: Can you please give li'l more detail on how to do it?

Comment: what is you kuberntes enviroment? these objects are stored in etcd

Comment: I'm using minikube

Comment: if you are using minikube , stop minikube , remove the kube direcotry from , and  then do a fresh minikube start , eceryhting will clean up

Comment: othervise connect to etcd and cleanup the key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807892/how-to-access-kubernetes-keys-in-etcd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182091/discussion-between-bitswazsky-and-ijaz-khan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 01**

Access the ETCD for minikube , find and clean up the key.

[Detailed procedure is here](https://jakubbujny.com/2018/09/02/what-stores-kubernetes-in-etcd/)

commands:

https://gist.github.com/iahmad-khan/5d32b4070b6faf3836b932a7177095ff

**Option 02 ( will lose the existing stuff )**

Stop minikube

Remove the kube direcotry  in user home ~/.minikube

Start a fresh minikube

Comment: I deleted the zookeeper service using kubectl. removed the release from helm. Stopped minikube. Deleted the .kube folder. Brought up minikube. But unfortunately still seeing the same issue. I guess I'll try out on a different machine, and see.

Comment: answer updated , go to etcd and see where the key exist

Comment: The second option is gaurreented to work , you may not have cleaned up the correct direcotry , it should be in the home of user , ~/.minikube . you need to delete that and start minikube again

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting the ~/.minikube dir messed up my minikube setup. Now it won't start anymore.

Comment: i have been doing it everyday , and everytime , minikune setups things from scatch

Comment: I use this command to install minikube `curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.30.0/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && cp minikube /usr/local/bin/` Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: it is not related to minkube installation , if you can run the minikube binary then it should be ok to delete the .minikube directory and start over , it will re-create it

Answer (score 32):

I think that the simplest solution is to **add the `--debug` flag for the installation command**:

```
helm install chart my-chart --debug
```

Or if you prefer:

```
helm  upgrade --install chart my-chart --debug
```

It displays all the resources which are created one by one and also related errors which occured during installation.

Comment: Well... I'm installing charts using terraform so everything could be done with just one command

Answer (score 6):

Do `helm list --all` - [Helm List](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/#helm)

Then if you have a conflicting release then probably need to delete the release again with the `--purge` flag

But it could possibly be that you have a Service object named `zookeeper` that isn't part of a helm release or that hasn't been cleaned up. You can check with `kubectl get services` (or add the `--all-namespaces` flag if it might be in a different namespace from your context). If so then you'll want to delete resources directly with `kubectl delete`

Comment: While listing all releases, I could see all (except the current one) releases were marked `DELETED`. I purged that one, but didn't help. I checked the services too, didn't find any conflict.

Comment: Perhaps try purging even the deleted ones?

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally got it working. Looks like there were some errors in my yaml file. But in this process I learnt how to properly cleanup a minikube instance. I executed the following commands to bring up a fresh minikube instance, in case anybody faces similar issue. This was done on CentOS 7. Thanks to @Ijaz for pointing me to the right direction.

```
minikube stop && minikube delete && rm -rf ~/.minikube && rm -rf ~/.kube
rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
rm -rf /var/lib/minikube/certs/
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```