# Errors when using etcdctl on Kubernetes cluster: "certificates signed by unknown authority"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, etcd, etcdctl

I have minikube running and I am trying to list the keys on my ETCD.

I downloaded the latest `etcdctl` client from github:
https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/releases/download/v3.3.18/etcd-v3.3.18-linux-amd64.tar.gz

I tried to run it with the certificates from `/home/myuser/.minikube/certs`:

```
./etcdctl --ca-file /home/myuser/.minikube/certs/ca.pem 
          --key-file /home/myuser/.minikube/certs/key.pem 
          --cert-file /home/myuser/.minikube/certs/cert.pem  
          --endpoints=https://10.240.0.23:2379 get /
```

I received an error:

> Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error
>   #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
>
> error #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Did I used the correct certificates ?

I tried different certificates like that:

```
./etcdctl --ca-file /var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt 
          --key-file /var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.key 
          --cert-file /var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.crt 
          --endpoints=https://10.240.0.23:2379 get /
```

I received the same error from before.

Any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the `ETCDCTL_API=3` before the commands.
I saw it being used in Kubernetes the Hard Way from this [Github](https://github.com/mmumshad/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/practice-questions-answers/cluster-maintenance/backup-etcd/etcd-backup-and-restore.md#2-backup).
The location of the certificate are in: `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd`.

The command should work like that:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 ./etcdctl --endpoints=https://172.17.0.64:2379 \
                        --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
                        --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
                        --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key get / --prefix
```

I tested it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For minikube the correct path for etcd certificates is: /var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ so the command will be like that:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system exec -it etcd-minikube -- sh -c "ETCDCTL_API=3 ETCDCTL_CACERT=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt ETCDCTL_CERT=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.crt ETCDCTL_KEY=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.key etcdctl endpoint health"
```

Comment: I was searching far too much for this. thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dump all etcd entries fully prefixed but from host/outside its container, you could also issue (here for minikube/local testing):

```
kubectl exec -it \
  -n kube-system etcd-minikube \
  -- sh -c 'ETCDCTL_CACERT=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt \
    ETCDCTL_CERT=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.crt \
    ETCDCTL_KEY=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/server.key \
    ETCDCTL_API=3  \
    etcdctl \
      get \
      --prefix=true /'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute below command:
`$ cat /etc/etcd.env` to list CA , CERT, KEY directories(actual path).

**TLS settings**

```
ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-k8s-m1.pem
ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-k8s-m1-key.pem
ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true
```

Then you will be possible to correct use certificates.

Then run command again:

```
./etcdctl --endpoints https://x.x.x.x:2379 
          --ca-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem 
          --cert-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-k8s-m1.pem 
          --key-file=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-k8s-m1-key.pem
```

More information you can find here: [etcd-certificates](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/3514).